# How to add link to Sublime Text?

Tags: terminal, macos, text-editor, sublimetext

Just installed fresh copy of `El Capitan` and as usual started to install stuff... And suddenly faced strange problem. I'm using `Sublime Text`. It provides `bin` called `subl`, which allow to use it from console. So I added link to it like:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

But when I try tuo use it from console i get:

```
MacBook-Pro-Kiril:~ $ subl
-bash: subl: command not found
MacBook-Pro-Kiril:~ $ ls /usr/loca/bin
ls: /usr/loca/bin: No such file or directory
MacBook-Pro-Kiril:~ $ ls /usr/local/bin
brew        mongo       mongodump   mongofiles  mongooplog  mongorestore    mongosniff  mongotop    npm
bsondump    mongod      mongoexport mongoimport mongoperf   mongos      mongostat   node        subl
MacBook-Pro-Kiril:~ $ ls /usr/local/bin/subl
/usr/local/bin/subl
MacBook-Pro-Kiril:~ $ ls -la /usr/local/bin/subl
lrwxr-xr-x  1   admin  63 Oct 28 19:42 /usr/local/bin/subl -> /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
MacBook-Pro-Kiril:~ $ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
connecting to: test
2015-10-28T20:22:18.219+0200 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2015-10-28T20:22:18.221+0200 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
MacBook-Pro-Kiril:~ $ which mongo
/usr/local/bin/mongo
```

As you can see other tuff from `/usr/local/bin` works fine. I also tried just for test create copy of nano and it worked fine...

```
MacBook-Pro-Kiril:~ $ nano
MacBook-Pro-Kiril:~ $ which nano
/usr/bin/nano
MacBook-Pro-Kiril:~ $ ln -s /usr/bin/nano /usr/local/bin/nano_2
MacBook-Pro-Kiril:~ $ nano_2
MacBook-Pro-Kiril:~ $ rm /usr/local/bin/nano_2
MacBook-Pro-Kiril:~ $ nano_2
-bash: /usr/local/bin/nano_2: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use one of the two forms shown below:

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Or:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

But do not mix both using quotes and backslashes to escape spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

You're using both quotes and `\`.